# Как создать отчёт в Битрикс-24?

Tags: php, битрикс, report

Стоит задача сделать отчёт по Количеству контактов на каждую Компанию в Битрикс-24 в разделе CRM > Старт.

Там я нажимаю кнопку "Сформировать отчёт", имеются только выборки, где выводятся имена сотрудников и количество сделок (активных, например).

Однако, в конструкторе отчётов из дополнительных полей возможно добавить лишь "Сумма с АК до НДС" и больше ничего.

Как же, обладая правами администратора, создать отчёт-график, где четко будут отображено: Количество контактов и Название компаний? Как добавить нужную комбинацию?

Имеются данные (список контактов по компаниям).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможности постороения такого отчета штатными средствами Битрикс24 нет. Для реализации такого отчета для облака необходимо писать приложение, которое будет строить такой отчет, для коробочной версии просто написать свой скрипт, который будет на отдельной странице выводить необходимые данные.